# matplotlib.animation shows empty graphs (NOT because of Jupyter notebook or too small markers)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

I am trying to make an animation, but the resulting graphs show up empty. My code can be found below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class SubplotAnimation(animation.TimedAnimation):
def __init__(self, F_vector, eta_atm, Pkid, Tb_sky):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

    self.F_vector = F_vector
    self.eta_atm = eta_atm
    self.Pkid = Pkid
    self.Tb_sky = Tb_sky

    self.t = np.linspace(0, 350, 350)

    ax1.set_xlabel('Frequency in GHz')
    ax1.set_ylabel('$\eta$')
    self.line1a = Line2D([], [], color='black', linewidth=3)
    self.line1b = Line2D([], [], color='red', linewidth=3)
    self.line1c = Line2D([], [], color='red', linewidth=3)
    self.line1d = Line2D([], [], color='yellow', linewidth=3)
    ax1.add_line(self.line1a)
    ax1.add_line(self.line1b)
    ax1.add_line(self.line1c)
    ax1.add_line(self.line1d)

    ax2.set_xlabel('$P_{kid}$ in W')
    ax2.set_ylabel('$T_{sky}$ in K')
    self.line2a = Line2D([], [], color='red', linewidth=3)
    self.line2b = Line2D([], [], color='green', linewidth=3)
    self.line2c = Line2D([], [], color='blue', linewidth=3)
    self.line2d = Line2D([], [], color='yellow', linewidth=3)
    ax2.add_line(self.line2a)
    ax2.add_line(self.line2b)
    ax2.add_line(self.line2c)
    ax2.add_line(self.line2d)

    animation.TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, interval=50, blit=True)

def _draw_frame(self, framedata):
    i = framedata

    self.line1a.set_data(self.F_vector, self.eta_atm[0, :])
    self.line1b.set_data(self.F_vector, self.eta_atm[1, :])
    self.line1c.set_data(self.F_vector, self.eta_atm[2, :])
    self.line1d.set_data(self.F_vector, self.eta_atm[3, :])

    self.line2a.set_data(self.Pkid[0, i, :], self.Tb_sky[0, i, :])
    self.line2b.set_data(self.Pkid[1, i, :], self.Tb_sky[1, i, :])
    self.line2c.set_data(self.Pkid[2, i, :], self.Tb_sky[2, i, :])
    self.line2d.set_data(self.Pkid[3, i, :], self.Tb_sky[3, i, :])

    self._drawn_artists = [self.line1a, self.line1b,self.line1c,
                           self.line1d, self.line2a, self.line2b,
                           self.line2c, self.line2d]

def new_frame_seq(self):
    return iter(range(self.t.size))

def _init_draw(self):
    lines = [self.line1a, self.line1b, self.line1c,
             self.line1d, self.line2a, self.line2b,
             self.line2c, self.line2d]
    for l in lines:
        l.set_data([], [])
SubplotAnimation_1 = SubplotAnimation(F_vector, eta_atm, Pkid, Tb_sky)
plt.show()
```

Where F_vector, eta_atm, Pkid, Tb_sky are matrices that are taken out of .txt files. I see the 2 subplots how I want to, with the right axis labels as well. However, there's nothing inside. I am running this program locally (not on Jupyter notebook) and as you can see, increasing the linewidth does not have any effect. Does anyone know why there is nothing showing up in the graph?

I would appreciate your help very much, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code isn't self-contained and hence not runnable to be able to test anything. I can therefore only suspect that the animation is simply happening outside of your axes boundaries and therefore not be seen.

Comment: Oh, that was exactly the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit of my problem was the boundary of the axes. Adding the code below to the **init** function made the program work:

```
ax1.set_xlim(np.min(self.F_vector), np.max(self.F_vector))
ax1.set_ylim(np.min(eta_atm), np.max(eta_atm)
ax2.set_xlim(0, np.max(self.Pkid))
ax2.set_ylim(0, np.max(self.Tb_sky))
```

Made it work :)